# organise data fetched from api

Tags: javascript, json

Hello i'm learning Javascript and its been 3 days that i'm trying to make it work.
I know it simple but everything i try doesn't work.

I need to organise the data fetched from an API

***I calling the api with axios***

```
axios.get('url').then(function (response) {
  console.log(response.data)
})
```

***the json that i get***

```
[{
  "item_id": "item_1",
  "city": "city_1",
  "quality": 2,
  "sell_price": 1000,
  "sell_price_date": "2020-05-05T01:20:00"
},
{
  "item_id": "item_1",
  "city": "city_2",
  "quality": 2,
  "sell_price": 1200,
  "sell_price_date": "2020-05-05T03:38:00"
},
{
  "item_id": "item_1",
  "city": "city_1",
  "quality": 3,
  "sell_price": 1400,
  "sell_price_date": "2020-05-05T01:20:00"
},
{
  "item_id": "item_1",
  "city": "city_2",
  "quality": 3,
  "sell_price": 1600,
  "sell_price_date": "2020-05-05T03:38:00",
},
{
  "item_id": "item_2",
  "city": "city_1",
  "quality": 2,
  "sell_price": 2000,
  "sell_price_date": "2020-05-05T01:20:00"
},
{
  "item_id": "item_2",
  "city": "city_2",
  "quality": 2,
  "sell_price": 2200,
  "sell_price_date": "2020-05-05T03:38:00",
},
{
  "item_id": "item_2",
  "city": "city_1",
  "quality": 3,
  "sell_price": 2400,
  "sell_price_date": "2020-05-05T01:20:00"
},
{
  "item_id": "item_2",
  "city": "city_2",
  "quality": 3,
  "sell_price": 2600,
  "sell_price_date": "2020-05-05T03:38:00",
}]
```

***I need to organise the data like this :***

```
[{
  "item_id": "item_1",
  "qualities": [
    {
      "quality": 2,
      "cities": [
        {
          "city": "city_1",
          "sell_price": 1000,
          "sell_price_date": "2020-05-05T03:38:00",
        },
        {
          "city": "city_2",
          "sell_price": 1200,
          "sell_price_date": "2020-05-05T03:38:00",
        }
        // More cities
      ]
    },
    {
      "quality": 3,
      "cities": [
        {
          "city": "city_1",
          "sell_price": 1400,
          "sell_price_date": "2020-05-05T03:38:00",
        },
        {
          "city": "city_2",
          "sell_price": 1600,
          "sell_price_date": "2020-05-05T03:38:00",
        }
        // More cities
      ]
    },
  ],
},
{
  "item_id": "item_2",
  "qualities": [
    {
      "quality": 2,
      "cities": [
        {
          "city": "city_1",
          "sell_price": 2000,
          "sell_price_date": "2020-05-05T03:38:00",
        },
        {
          "city": "city_2",
          "sell_price": 2200,
          "sell_price_date": "2020-05-05T03:38:00",
        }
        // More cities
      ]
    },
    {
      "quality": 3,
      "cities": [
        {
          "city": "city_1",
          "sell_price": 2400,
          "sell_price_date": "2020-05-05T03:38:00",
        },
        {
          "city": "city_2",
          "sell_price": 2600,
          "sell_price_date": "2020-05-05T03:38:00",
        }
        // More cities
      ]
    },
  ],
}
// More items
]
```

***And then i will create html from the organised data(pseudo code)***

```
<ul class="items" >
  ${db.forEach(item => {
      <li class="item">
        <p class="item_title">item.item_id</p>
        <ul class="item_qualities">

          ${item.qualities.forEach(qual => {
            <li class="quality">
              <p class="quality_title">qual.quality</p>
              <ul class="cities">

                ${qual.cities.forEach(city => {
                <li class="city">
                  <p class="city_title">city.city</p>
                  <ul class="prices">
                    <li class="sell_price">
                      <p class="sell_price_title">city.sell_price</p>
                    </li>
                    <li class="sell_price_date">
                      <p class="sell_price_date_title">city.sell_price_date</p>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              })}

              </ul>
            </li>
          })}

        </ul>
      </li>
  })}
</ul >
```

***conclusion*** 
I new in javascript and programming in general, just trying to learn by using real data from api.
It would be nice if you can help me figure out how to do it.
If you have any tutorials about json and database that you think i should watch, i will be very happy if you can put the link :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point is about `GROUP`, isn't it?
I can see the group's first level is `item_id` from your code, but what is the second? `qualities` group by what?

```
var db = []
arr.forEach(e1 => {
    if (db.every(e2 => e2.item_id != e1.item_id)) {
        db.push({
            item_id: e1.item_id,
            qualities: [{
                quality: e1.quality,
                cities: [{
                    city: e1.city,
                    sell_price: e1.sell_price,
                    sell_price_date: e1.sell_price_date
                }]
            }]
        })
    } else {
        for (let i = 0; i < db.length; i++) {
            if (db[i].item_id === e1.item_id) {
                let qualities = db[i].qualities
                var flag = false
                for (let j = 0; j < qualities.length; j++) {
                    if (qualities[j].quality === e1.quality) {
                        qualities[j].cities = qualities[j].cities || []
                        qualities[j].cities.push({
                            city: e1.city,
                            sell_price: e1.sell_price,
                            sell_price_date: e1.sell_price_date
                        })
                        flag = true
                        break
                    }
                }
                if (!flag) {
                    db[i].qualities.push({
                        quality: e1.quality,
                        cities: [{
                            city: e1.city,
                            sell_price: e1.sell_price,
                            sell_price_date: e1.sell_price_date
                        }]
                    })
                    break
                }
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks that's really is usefiull !
The idea is :
MainGrp item_id 
 SecondGrp qualities
  ThirdGrp cities

Comment: Got it. It's my mistake, I'm looking in the wrong: quantity &  quality. So I'm confused, embarrassing...

Comment: ok i have a new problem, i get an error i will put the code in an answer, do you have any ideas what is the problem ?

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'qualities' of undefined
    at index.js:33
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at index.js:9

Comment: figure out the logic, the object must be initialized before use (here is push)

Comment: Thanks you very much i understand now, thanks for your time an have a nice day :)

Answer (score 0):

You do not create the database straight from JSON, but rather see what attributes you receive from json and figure our which ones you need. Once you know that you can architect the fields of the database along with each fields proper type

Once you have the DB created, you can start pulling data from the api, and cycle through the received entries and insert each one in yor DB.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't really talking about databases here. Your question more has to do with how to transform the data coming back from the API into something that you will use. A database would be a tool used for persisting that data.

Use JavaScript `forEach()` method to iterate through each element and implement your logic to push each element to your transormed set.

```
var transformedData = []    
response.data.forEach(item => {
  ...logic to add or update items in transformed set
})
```

I'll give you a hint. First thing you need to do is check to see if the item already exists in the `transformedData` set.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks that usefiull !

Answer (score 0):

***Current state :***

```
function fetchData() {
  console.log("start fetching !")

  axios.get('url')
    .then(function (response) {
      response.data.forEach(e1 => {

        if (db.every(e2 => e2.item_id != e1.item_id)) {

          console.log("item not found, create new")
          db.push(
            {
              item_id: e1.item_id,
              qualities: [{
                quality: e1.quality,
                cities: [{
                  city: e1.city,
                  sell_price_min: e1.sell_price_min,
                  sell_price_min_date: e1.sell_price_min_date
                }]
              }]
            })

        } else {

          console.log("item found edit it")
          item_index = db.indexOf(e1.item_id)
          console.log(item_index)

          if (db[item_index].qualities.every(e3 => e3.quality != e1.quality)) {

            console.log("quality not found, create new")
            db[item_index].qualities.push(
              {
                quality: e1.quality,
                cities: [{
                  city: e1.city,
                  sell_price_min: e1.sell_price_min,
                  sell_price_min_date: e1.sell_price_min_date
                }]
              })

          } else {

            console.log("quality found, edit it")
            quality_index = db[item_index].qualities.indexOf(e1.quality)
            console.log(quality_index)

            if (db[item_index].qualities[quality_index].cities.every(
              e4 => e4.city != e1.city)) {

              console.log("city not found, create new")
              db[item_index].qualities[quality_index].cities.push(
                {
                  city: e1.city,
                  sell_price_min: e1.sell_price_min,
                  sell_price_min_date: e1.sell_price_min_date
                })

            } else {

              console.log("city found, edit it")
              city_index = db[item_index].qualities[quality_index].cities.indexOf(e1.city)
              console.log(city_index)

              db[item_index].qualities[quality_index].cities[city_index].city = e1.city;
              db[item_index].qualities[quality_index].cities[city_index].sell_price_min = e1.sell_price_min;
              db[item_index].qualities[quality_index].cities[city_index].sell_price_min_date = e1.sell_price_min_date;

            }
          }

        }

      });

      console.log("fetchinge ended")
      console.log(db)
    })
}
```

***The error***

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'qualities' of undefined
    at index.js:33
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at index.js:9
```